# Kubernetes + CoreOS + Ceph RBD

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, ceph

Anyone has success or pointer on using the kubernetes to create a pod that mounts ceph rbd within the docker container?

The following example from kubernetes uses Fedora 21 with installation of ceph binaries, which won't work in CoreOS.

http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/rbd/

or

http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2015/06/29/bring-persistent-storage-for-your-containers-with-krbd-on-kubernetes/

Answer (score 3):

the project has evolved quite a bit. You can find the docker containers for CoreOS at

https://github.com/ceph/ceph-docker

Comment: oops, somehow missed that when copying. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

[CoreOS Toolbox](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/install-debugging-tools.html) might be helpful. Simply run `/usr/bin/toolbox` and you should be able to install Ceph via `yum`.

Comment: This looks interesting but I believe it actually spin up the fedora container and doesn't expose the ceph library within CoreOS after yum install.

Comment: Did you try http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2014-August/042063.html ? Is there a better way now?